# Warning: An update to UsernameForm inside a test was not wrapped in act(...)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have 2 components, one in function style and one in class style. I am testing them with jest and react/testing library. When I ran the function component I get this error. When I ran the class component I don't get this error. What is the difference between the function and class component here?

> Warning: An update to UsernameForm inside a test was not wrapped in
> act(...).
>
> ```
>   When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
>   
>   act(() => {
>     /* fire events that update state */
>   });
>   /* assert on the output */
> ```

**Function Component**

```
function UsernameForm({ updateUsername }) {
  const [{ status, error }, setState] = React.useState({
    status: "idle",
    error: null,
  });

  async function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const newUsername = event.target.elements.username.value;
    setState({ status: "pending" });
    try {
      await updateUsername(newUsername);
      setState({ status: "fulfilled" });
    } catch (e) {
      setState({ status: "rejected", error: e });
    }
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
      <input id="username" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      <span>{status === "pending" ? "Saving..." : null}</span>
      <span>{status === "rejected" ? error.message : null}</span>
    </form>
  );
}
```

**Class Component**

```
class UsernameFormClass extends React.Component {
  state = { status: "idle", error: null };
  handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const newUsername = event.target.elements.username.value;
    this.setState({ status: "pending" });
    try {
      await this.props.updateUsername(newUsername);
      this.setState({ status: "fulfilled" });
    } catch (e) {
      this.setState({ status: "rejected", error: e });
    }
  };
  render() {
    const { error, status } = this.state;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
        <input id="username" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <span>{status === "pending" ? "Saving..." : null}</span>
        <span>{status === "rejected" ? error.message : null}</span>
      </form>
    );
  }
}


test("calls updateUsername with the new username", async () => {
  const handleUpdateUsername = jest.fn();
  const fakeUsername = "sonicthehedgehog";

  render(<UsernameForm updateUsername={handleUpdateUsername} />);

  const usernameInput = screen.getByLabelText(/username/i);
  user.type(usernameInput, fakeUsername);
  user.click(screen.getByText(/submit/i));

  expect(handleUpdateUsername).toHaveBeenCalledWith(fakeUsername);
});
```

Comment: You should use two separate `useState` for `status` and `error` in functional components. `setState({ status: "pending" })` just makes `error` undefined which works accidentally here.

Comment: @Dominik i dont get what this is have to do with the warning act

Comment: I don't think it's cause for the warning which is why I added it as a comment and not as an answer...

Comment: Ok thanks. So you dont know the answer? The only difference here is that  we have class and function. The implementation is the same.

Comment: You really should separate the state though. And maybe that fixes your warning? Worth a try. The implementation of both is WILDLY different but your port is almost the same apart form the state.

Comment: I did change it. Is completely unrelated with the issue.

Comment: Great. Than we both know the same about this issue :)